# Fetching 1000s of employees with BambooHR API

Tags: node.js, pagination

#### Summary

The [BambooHR API documentation](https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/request-custom-report-1) makes no mention of pagination. It's difficult to test with 1000s of records. How can this endpoint be used to fetch 1000s of records? Typically, APIs would return a page number but I don't seem to see one here.

Is there a recommended procedure to handle this to ensure stability?

#### Sample code

```
// Endpoint to fetch employee info from
const url = `https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/example_subdomain/v1/reports/custom`;

const auth =
    "Basic " +
    Buffer.from("example_auth:x", "utf-8").toString("base64");

const postRes = await Axios.post(url, {
  fields: [
    "firstName",
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: auth,
      },
    },
  ],
});

// Get list of returned employees. How reliable is list here??
const employees = postRes.data.employees || [];
```

https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/request-custom-report-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak specifically for Bamboo, and 'ensure stability' isn't qualified too well... but if each user record is about (for example) 1KB, at a 1000 records that's 1MB. A big string, but should not be an issue for most programming languages or a single HTTP request.

If you're worried about something, why don't you mock the response, increase the number to 10,000 users and keep increasing until you see a problem.